# Updated my jailbroken iPhone 4s to 6.1.3, stuck in Recov. loop

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, recovery

My iPhone 4s was jailbroken, I think at 5.something or 6.0. I wish I remembered. I tried to update it to 6.1.3 via my phone in the settings menu. It restarted and told me to connect to iTunes.

I connected to iTunes to restore and got a 3194 error. I tried tinyumbrella but I cant kick my phone out of recovery mode. I went into DFU mode and used tinyumbrellas "fix recovery" options with no luck, iTunes returned a 21 error. I went back into DFU mode and tried to restore my phone through iTunes again, but now that I'm in DFU mode, I'm getting a 1600 error.

I updated iTunes to 11.0.2 (latest) and tried to restore again. Instead of immediately throwing an error, it's now downloading the iPhone software update and has 75 minutes remaining.

Not sure if this will make a single difference when it actually tries to install it, but in the meantime does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score -1):

If you jailbreak then update with the OTA function, your phone will have serious problems. I hope everything works out for you.

Comment: To whomever downvoted this, what did I say wrong?